# Motorola Surfboard SB6121 modem conected to 2WIREi38HG wireless router but there's no internet access

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem

I have just switched to Comcast cable internet from AT&T Uverse and I was hoping to use the 2WIRE wireless router with the new Surfboard modem so I can have wireless access.
I messed around with some settings and got it working for my laptop (I'm not terribly well versed in computer stuff; I think it was mostly luck) for about a week. 
The other day I tried to get online and there was no internet connection. I restarted the equipment with no success and then plugged the modem directly into the laptop. This worked, so I knew there was no outage. I connected the ethernet cord to the router and a second cord to my laptop and that worked, too. But when I tried again just with the wireless the laptop connects to the router, but doesn't recognize it or find an internet connection.

I tried to go to http://gateway.2Wire.net to fiddle with the settings, but all I get is a Server Not Found page. I tried to check the ip address but this is really kind of over my head and I get different things checking it while plugged into only the modem vs when I plug into the router.

Can anyone help? The frustrating thing is that I had it working for awhile, so I know it can do it!

Comment: which Operating system are you running from the wireless laptop?